# Fstab mounting fails when remote share is OFF

Tags: fstab

I have an entry in fstab to mount at boot a remote share which works fine when the local box boots finds remote box ON. The issue is when the local box starts and the remote box is OFF. The workaround is to mount manualy which is a bit annoying. I am just wondering if there is a better way to acomplish this task, something like an auto mounting when the remote box status change to ONLINE.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no way you can mount a share at system startup if the machine exporting that share is not up at that time. It's like trying to access a web page while the web server is down :). You must repeat the mount when server becomes available. However. You may write a script that checks if the share is available and mounts it if yes, and put that script in crontab so that it executes every 5 minutes or so...

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for, but at least your boot won't hang when the remote is down. Otherwise you'd need to write a short script to check for remote up, and then mount share.

Edit your /etc/fstab and try adding `nofail` like the example I show below...

```
//caspurr.local/usb_storage  /media/my_username/caspurrshare  cifs  nofail,gue
st,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks heynnema, I tried that, no work... noauto - The filesystem will NOT be automatically mounted at startup, or when mount passed -a. You must explicitly mount the filesystem.

Comment: @BradThompson No sooner did I post this answer, and I corrected it. Changed from noauto to nofail. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BradThompson Status please...

Comment: sorry, what you mean 'status' ?

Comment: @BradThompson Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: No. There are no errors but the share is not mounted (obviously). My original question was dumb. Thanks!